# EAR modules in m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2e, eclipse-wtp

I'm converting an existing project structure to Maven where there's EJBs and JARs contained in EARs that are deployed. My issue is with making EARs. It seems obvious to use the [Maven EAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/), which either takes an existing `application.xml` or generates one on basis of `configuration.modules`. I feel I'm not entirely leveraging Maven if I would not use the `modules` configuration (although it would allow developers to reuse the existing `application.xml` editor), but I'm thinking about many of our developers who love to click around in RAD/Eclipse to get things configured. So I took a look at RAD/Eclipse in full expectation to see some m2e support that would allow me to point-and-pick my EAR modules, and then see the `modules` in the POM file being populated accordingly. But I'm not able to find such thing. I believe I installed m2e (1.3.0) and m2e-wtp (0.17.0) although it seems to bring me very little in terms of WTP/EAR support. Also I spent most of tonight googling around, to no avail. Should I forget about it and have devs just manually edit the POM file, or am I overlooking some nifty UI for this purpose? Thanks for your pointers!

---

Seeing a comment and an answer that drive me to elaborate. I do appreciate that when using Maven, Maven is leading. No argument there. And I know that I can take control over the `application.xml` back using `generateApplicationXml`, but that's not even what I'm after, again Maven can be leading. But as I can use the "Maven POM Editor" to edit the basic structure of the POM, would there be any UI available to edit the `configuration.modules`? Our devs are very acustomed to IDE-centric development, and them having to start editing POM file XML in order to manage modules is something that scares me slightly...

Comment: Sorry but if you go to Maven you need to forget the IDE as source of configuration (like clicking and configuring). Maven is the source of the truth. Furthermore do you have a working build with a separate EAR module in Maven? Does your build work on command line? I assume having a multi-module build? Yes?

Comment: Thank you for that. I updated my question. I do appreciate that when using Maven, Maven is leading. But as I can use the "Maven POM Editor" to edit the basic structure of the POM, would there be any UI available to edit the `configuration.modules`? No, I'm only in the process of automating the conversion between existing `application.xml` files into `configuration.modules` configuration. It's indeed a multi-module build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure your application.xml manually you can include the file to your source folder and set the **generateApplicationXml** property to **false** so maven will not overwrite it.

See for details: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/generate-application-xml-mojo.html#generateApplicationXml